# C# How do I get a child from a list containing both parents and children

Tags: c#

I have a list of parents, let's suppose, `Wild`:

```
public class AnimalGroup {
  string name;
  int quantity;
  ...
}


List<AnimalGroup> Wild = new List<AnimalGroup>();
```

And children of `AnimalGroup`; `GiraffeGroup` and `LionGroup`:

```
public class LionGroup : AnimalGroup {
  
...
}

public class GiraffeGroup : AnimalGroup {
  float neckLength;
...
}
```

Now, I'd like to register the animals I created into the `Wild` list:

```
Wild.Add(new LionGroup("AfricanLions", 100));
Wild.Add(new GiraffeGroup("CanadianGiraffes", 200));
Wild.Add(new GiraffeGroup("AntarcticGiraffes", 50));
Wild.Add(new LionGroup("BasementLions", 700));
```

Now, I am trying to create a new list, let's say, `Zoo`. And I am going to create objects in this `Zoo` according to the information from the list `Wild`:

```
List<AnimalGroup> Zoo = new List<AnimalGroup>();

foreach(AnimalGroup animalGroup in Wild) {
  animalGroup.quantity -= 10;
  if(animalGroup is Giraffe) {
    Zoo.Add(new Giraffe(animalGroup.name, 10));
  }
  else if(animalGroup is Lion) {
    Zoo.Add(new Lion(animalGroup.name, 10));
  }
  else {
    Zoo.Add(new animalGroup(animalGroup.name, 10));
  }
}
```

See what I had to do there? For every single type of animals I had, I had to separately check their types and do the same action for different types. This is extremely inefficient and I feel stupid for having to do this. Is there anything else I can do in this situation?

Comment: What's your goal ? Are you trying to duplicate the groups from the `Wild` list  into the `Zoo` list with a `quantity` of 10 ?

Comment: Your goal is to get a copy of a class without knowing what class it is?

Comment: @Hervé yes, that's what I was trying to do.

Comment: Sounds like a case where you should be using composition (AnimalType as an enum property) rather than inheritance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve a better solution using polymorphism in derrived types.

Declare a method in the base class that addeds the groups to the list.

```
public class AnimalGroup 
{
    string name;
    int quantity;
  
    public virtual void AddToZoo(List<AnimalGroup> zoo, int number)
    {
        zoo.Add(new AnimalGroup(animalGroup.name, number));
    }
}
```

override the method in the child classes, referring to the child class when adding to the list.

```
public class LionGroup : AnimalGroup 
{
    public override void AddToZoo(List<AnimalGroup> zoo, int number)
    {
        zoo.Add(new LionGroup(animalGroup.name, number));
    }
}
```

call `AddToZoo` in the loop and the program will call the method in the derrived types.

```
foreach(AnimalGroup animalGroup in Wild) 
{
    animalGroup.quantity -= 10;
    animalGroup.AddToZoo(Zoo, 10);
}
```

Note: you may want to mark `AnimalGroup` as abstract as you don't ever want to create an instance of `AnimalGroup`. You can also mark `AddToZoo` as abstract to ensure that child classes override it.

Comment: thanks, seems very simple and effective. i'll just roll with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generally know if one class is derived from another you can use

```
Type.IsSubclassOf()
```

method

But for creating class instances it's better to know your types.

If you really want you can use Reflection but I won't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

You could encapsulate your zoo in a class `Zoo`, and implement the logic you want to perform. In this case, setting the animal groups's `Quantity` to 10 and store it.

## Using classes

First, you need to define how to do the copy

```cs
public abstract class AnimalGroup
{
    protected AnimalGroup(string name, int quantity)
    {
        Name = name;
        Quantity = quantity;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
    public int Quantity { get; private set; }

    protected abstract AnimalGroup Clone();

    public AnimalGroup CopyWithQuantity(int quantity)
    {
        var clone = Clone();
        clone.Quantity = quantity;

        return clone;
    }
}

public class LionGroup : AnimalGroup
{
    public LionGroup(string name, int quantity)
        : base(name, quantity)
    {
    }

    protected override AnimalGroup Clone()
    {
        return new LionGroup(Name, Quantity);
    }
}

public class GiraffeGroup : AnimalGroup
{
    public GiraffeGroup(string name, int quantity, float neckLenght)
        : base(name, quantity)
    {
        NeckLenght = neckLenght;
    }

    public float NeckLenght { get; }

    protected override AnimalGroup Clone()
    {
        return new GiraffeGroup(Name, Quantity, NeckLenght);
    }
}
```

Then, define the `Zoo`

```cs
public class Zoo
{
    private readonly List<AnimalGroup> animalGroups = new();

    public void AddGroup(AnimalGroup group)
    {
        var copy = group.CopyWithQuantity(10);
        animalGroups.Add(copy);
    }
}
```

Finally, you could do something like

```cs
var zoo = new Zoo();

foreach (var group in wild)
{
    zoo.AddGroup(group);
}
```

## Using records

Things get mush easier using the builtin `record` as you can perform the clone using the `with` keyword.

```cs
public abstract record AnimalGroup(string Name, int Quantity);

public record LionGroup(string Name, int Quantity) : AnimalGroup(Name, Quantity);

public record GiraffeGroup(string Name, int Quantity, float NeckLenght) : AnimalGroup(Name, Quantity);

public class Zoo
{
    private readonly List<AnimalGroup> animalGroups = new();

    public void AddGroup(AnimalGroup group)
    {
        var copy = group with { Quantity = 10 };
        animalGroups.Add(copy);
    }
}
```

Comment: The part that the instances in Zoo are different from the one in Wild seemed relevant. At least that the problem he had getting a "copy" with changed Quantity only. Actually the logic operation is splitting the group by quantity-

Comment: @Ralf your right, I'll update my answer